# How to properly handle a navigation stack with React Native tvOS / Android TV

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tvos, android-tv

I am using react-native-tvos to build a tvOS and Amazon FireStick app. However I am running into a problem with react-navigation. Screens that are added to the navigation stack are still active in the background. This causes the focus engine to get confused. Using the directional pad on the remote the focus will shift between the non-visible screen on the bottom of the stack and the currently displayed screen. I am looking for suggestions on how to solve this problem.

I have read that other people have experienced this problem with react-navigation and react-native-navigation. But I did not find solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-native-tvos` version, then follow [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tvos/issues/43) in their repo.

As for a temporary solution, I can recommend hiding your content yourself.
Take a look at my implementation:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

// That's a HOC to know when the current Screen is focused
import withScreenFocusing from "../components/HOC/WithScreenFocusing";

const FocusHider = ({ isFocused, children }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ display: isFocused ? "flex" : "none" }}>{children}</View>
  );
};

export default withScreenFocusing(FocusHider);
```

And then use it as such:

```
 <FocusHider>
   <YourAwesomeContent />
 </FocusHider>
```

Just in case, the HOC I mentioned there is just `useIsFocused` from `@react-navigation/native`

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on AndroidTV project and experienced focus problems with
react-native-navigation too.
When I navigate to other screens, the focus of the Touchable components is ignored.
I managed to solve that by adding the react-native-screens package (which react-native-navigation defined it as a must dependency) then in my app.js I added:

```
import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens';
enableScreens();
```

Then the focus has been returned to work as expected.

I Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I have a problem where the focus when returning back to a screen always goes to the first touchable component and not to the component which triggered the showing of second screen. Can you help me ?

Comment: @user3396084 same problem , if you solved this problem please share the solution.